# Dropdown list with AJAX request and response back in JSON format not working

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I want all state name of id 1 from static PHP array using ajax request and convert response in json.why it is not running, or it is a wrong way to do so??
country is coming from database and got set.

```js
$(document).ready(function()
 {

            $("#country_drop").change(function()
            {
            var cuid = $(this).val();

            alert(cuid);
         $.ajax(
                  {
                    url: 'get_state.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {id2:cuid},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success:function(data)
                    {

                        var len = data.length;

                        $("#state_drop").empty();

                        $('#state_drop').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>'); 
                        for( var i = 0; i<len; i++)
                        {
                          //  var id = data[i]['id'];
                            //var name = data[i]['name'];

                         // $("#state_drop").append('<option value="'+id+'">'+name+'</option>');


                        $('#state_drop').append('<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+ data[i].name+'</option>');

                        }
                        }
                    });

                    });

            });
```

Comment: Please check the console for error(s). Make sure you have set the correct url of state list api. i.e `get_state.php`. If the Ajax call is OK it will trigger the `success()` callback.

Please search further on SO or internet you can find resources to serve JSON from php api, before posting the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ajax json response array using in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770691/ajax-json-response-array-using-in-php)

Comment: Where's your server side script?

Comment: IF($country==1)
{
   windows.alert("hi"); 
    $state_arr[] = array("GUJARAT"=>1,"RAJESHTHAN"=>2,"MAHARASTRA"=>3);
    foreach($state_arr as $state_name=>$id)
    {
        $state_arr= array('name'=>$state_name,'id'=>$id); 
    }
    echo json_encode($state_arr);
}
 else {
windows.alert("hi");    
}